# Cardinality of all subsets of cardinality $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of all subsets of cardinality $\aleph_0$ in $\mathbb{R}$?
And of all subsets of cardinality $\aleph$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Since both are subsets of $P(\mathbb{R})$ , I conclude both have cardinality less or equal to $2^{\aleph}$.
How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $\mathcal P_\kappa(A)$ mean $\{X\subseteq A\mid |X|=\kappa\}$. Then
$$f(X)=\{e^x\mid x\in X\} \cup[-1,0]$$
defines an injection $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)\to\mathcal P_\aleph(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Cool solution! Just to see I understood, can I also choose $\sqrt{x}$ united with [-1,0) or $2^x$ united with [-1,0]?

Comment: @Whyka: $\sqrt x$ won't work, since that is not defined on all of $\mathbb R$, but $2^x$ will.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Assuming the axiom of choice, you can choose for each subset an injective function from $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R$ whose range is that set. So you only need to count the functions, namely you need to calculate the cardinals $\aleph^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph^\aleph$.

[Without the axiom of choice it is consistent that the set of all countable subsets of $\Bbb R$ has a cardinality which is strictly larger than $\aleph^{\aleph_0}$. Strange, but possible.]

Comment: Am I correct if I calculate $\aleph^{\aleph_0}=\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph$?

Comment: $\aleph$ *is* $2^{\aleph_0}$ here.

Comment: I assumed as much. I asked if my cardinal arithmetic is correct? Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.